# Can I add words/image over an embedded Vimeo iframe? How?

Tags: html, iframe, embed, embedded-resource, vimeo

As title... Can I even do that? If so, how to? I've embedded a Vimeo video but failed to add words on it. Javascript is able to use
Many thanks

Comment: Just layer a span-tag over your video tag. Put both your video-tag and a span-tag inside a container-div. The container-div has `position:relative;` and both the video-tag and the span-tag have `position:absolute;` Then set the span tag to your desired text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with a text with an absolute position:

```css
#video-container{
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
}

#foreground-text{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;width:100%;text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  
  color: white;font: bold 20px;

}
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/36477715" width="100%" height="300"  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/36477715">Things Programmers Also Know</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/bluekeyes">Billy Keyes</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
  <span id="foreground-text">Some text</span>
  
</div>
```

(video won't work in the snippet frame)

You can also use WebVTT subtitles:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video
- http://html5doctor.com/video-subtitling-and-webvtt/

Comment: Hi, this works fine when video is not in fullscreen, but when video is dispalyed in fullscreen mode, the span text is hidden. When using the inspector tool and place pointer over the span tag, the container can be seen but not the text. How can be this tackled?